# Add folder in Netbeans left sidebar

Tags: window, netbeans

This is the section I am talking about. Generally I work on MVC projects. And for same controller, relevant model, and templates are in completely different directories. Is it possible to use a directory as a tab here like "Projects", "Favorites",..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One of the method I earlier found is to drop folder into the editor and they will be added as tab in left sidebar.

Unfortunately this method doesn't persist across session. The minute you close the IDE, you have to add all folders again.

If anybody still know a better solution (on project level) with persistence across sessions, do let me know.